# How do I specify options params in Handlebars.java?

Tags: java, handlebars.js, handlebars.java

As per the Handlebars.java documentation, there is an Options class which has a params object that can be accessed. My question is, how do I write a template + input JSON, which will populate this Options.param object?

API Documentation that shows Options param function: http://javadox.com/com.github.jknack/handlebars/1.3.1/com/github/jknack/handlebars/Options.java.html

Answer (score 2):

Found my own answer. Options are specified in the template, not in the input data. Any params passed to a helper function, after the context argument, will be options. For example:

Template:

`{{yourHelperFunction context "option1" "option2"}}`

Input data:

```
{ 

    "someData" :"data" 

}
```

Java code:

```
    public yourHelperFunction(String context, Option options){
        if (options.param(0) == "option1") /*do something */
    }
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, however I have used options.param(0);